# What's the correct way to write an if statement with the return value of a function with arguments?

Tags: bash

I'm not sure on the correct way to write an if statement that is calculated on the return value of a function that has arguments.

```
if [ ColumnCountGood "0" -a ColumnCountGood "1" -a ColumnCountGood "2" -a Counter > 10 ]
then
return 1
else
return 0
fi
```

I try the above but get an error for too many arguments.

Comment: Probably safest to wrap the function calls in $()

Comment: Do you mean the `return` value of a function?

Comment: I mean on the return value of the function ColumnCountGood in this example

Comment: The syntax to run commands while checking their return code in a condition for you would be `if ColumnCountGood "0" && ColumnCountGood "1" && ColumnCountGood "2" && [ $Counter -gt 10 ]`

Comment: This one worked for me, if you post as answer you can get it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to run commands while checking their return code in a condition for you would be

```
if ColumnCountGood "0" && ColumnCountGood "1" && ColumnCountGood "2" && [ $Counter -gt 10 ]
```